# Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

My code checks if a user is available. See snippet below:

```
const users = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4']
const usersToAdd = 2

const getRandomWorker = (userArray) => {
  return userArray[Math.floor(userArray.length * Math.random())]
}

const availableUsers = []

for (let i = 0; i < usersToAdd; i += i) {
  let randomWorker = getRandomWorker(users)
  let didAddWorker = false

  while (!didAddWorker) {
    if (checkIfUserAvailable(randomWorker)) {
      availableUsers.push(randomWorker)
      users = users.filter((user) => user !== randomWorker)
      didAddWorker = true
    } else if (!users.length) {
      didAddWorker = true
    } else {
      users = users.filter((user) => user !== randomWorker)
    }
  }
}
```

My only problem is that it contains unsafe references to variables(s) because I get the following error:

```
Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) randomWorker.
```

I've searched around and fiddled with my code but I can't get rid of the error. I don't know where to look anymore.

Comment: `(user) => user !== randomWorker` is being created in every loop. Maybe the linter is telling you to make this a function outside the loop and pass the function reference to `filter`?

Comment: This is just a linter going overboard, I'd probably turn that warning off. There's nothing wrong with those inline functions. You *could* factor them out, create a function that returns a function (`const notEqualTo = (target) => (element) => element !== target;`) and use that, but it's usually overkill.

Comment: It's *true* that functions in loops closing over variables being modified can be a problem (see [this question and its answers for instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)), it just isn't one here.

Comment: Above I suggested a function returning a function, but really you could just have a simple utility function: `const filterOut = (array, target) => array.filter(element => element !== target);` and then you'd use it as `users = filterOut(users, randomWorker);`. Simpler than the function-returning-function (though the latter is more flexible).

Answer (score 0):

As T.J Crowder suggested I had to make a function outside of the loop:

```
const filterOut = (array, target) => array.filter(element => element !== target);
```

That fixed it. A bit strange but I can continue know. Thanks!